# multiprocessing spawning processes without pooling

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, zombie-process

I am trying to use the multiprocessing library to spawn new processes without using a Pool and without creating zombies.

> On Unix when a process finishes but has not been joined it becomes a
> zombie. There should never be very many because each time a new
> process starts (or `active_children()` is called) all completed
> processes which have not yet been joined will be joined. Also calling
> a finished process’s `Process.is_alive` will join the process. Even so
> it is probably good practice to explicitly join all the processes that
> you start.

This implementation is a short version of a bigger script that creates zombies after some hours :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def target(task):
    print(f"Working for {task*2} seconds ...")
    time.sleep(task*2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = 4
    list_process = [None] * processes
    targets = [[2] for i in range(10)]

    list_process = [None] * processes
    while targets:
        for i in range(processes):
            p = list_process[i]
            if not (p and p.is_alive()):
                list_process[i] = Process(target=target, args=(targets.pop(0)))
                list_process[i].start()
                if p:
                    p.join()

    for process in list_process:
        if process:
            process.join()
```

On the bigger version, `list_process` has only zombies and no more task can be processed.

**Update 1**

Thanks to [Booboo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823719/booboo), I was able to get better sight of what is happening :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def target(task):
    print(f"Working for {task*2} seconds ...")
    time.sleep(task*2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    started_count = 0
    joined_count = 0
    joined_list = []
    processes = 4
    list_process = [None] * processes
    targets = [[2] for i in range(10)]

    list_process = [None] * processes
    while targets:
        for i in range(processes):
            p = list_process[i]
            if not (p and p.is_alive()):
                list_process[i] = Process(target=target, args=(targets.pop(0)))
                list_process[i].start()
                print(list_process[i].pid)
                started_count += 1
                if p:
                    assert(not p.is_alive())
                    p.join()
                    joined_list.append(list_process[i].pid)
                    joined_count += 1

    for process in list_process:
        if process:
            process.join()
            joined_list.append(list_process[i].pid)
            joined_count += 1

    print(f'Final started count: {started_count}, final joined count: {joined_count}')
    print(joined_list)
```

Output :

```
20604
24108
1272
23616
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
18492
17348
19992
6216
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
18744
26240
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Final started count: 10, final joined count: 10
[18492, 17348, 19992, 6216, 18744, 26240, 6216, 6216, 6216, 6216]
```

I have 10 processes that are joined but some are not the good ones (the pid *6216* has not been invoked for a task, and the first ones are not joined), leading to not joined processes, why ?

Comment: There are somehow some processes that are not `.join()` leading to zombie processes (simple inference from the documentation mentioned). As the number of simultaneous processes has a maximum value with the list `list_process`, not all tasks are being completed.

Comment: I think that inside the `while`-loop, after `if p:`, `joined_list.append(list_process[i].pid)` should be `joined_list.append(p.pid)`? Also, imho, you could run into trouble: There could be more `pop`s than elements in `targets`.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this code before and *as far as it goes*, it seems correct. I have modified it to keep track of the number of times processes are started and joined and added an assertion just as a "sanity check":

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def target(task):
    print(f"Working for {task*2} seconds ...")
    time.sleep(task*2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    started_count = 0
    joined_count = 0
    processes = 4
    list_process = [None] * processes
    targets = [[2] for i in range(10)]

    list_process = [None] * processes
    while targets:
        for i in range(processes):
            p = list_process[i]
            if not (p and p.is_alive()):
                list_process[i] = Process(target=target, args=(targets.pop(0)))
                list_process[i].start()
                started_count += 1
                print('started count:', started_count)
                if p:
                    assert(not p.is_alive())
                    p.join()
                    joined_count += 1
                    print('joined count:', joined_count)

    for process in list_process:
        if process:
            process.join()
            joined_count += 1
            print('joined count:', joined_count)

    print(f'Final started count: {started_count}, final joined count: {joined_count}')
```

Prints:

```
started count: 1
started count: 2
started count: 3
started count: 4
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
started count: 5
joined count: 1
started count: 6
joined count: 2
started count: 7
joined count: 3
started count: 8
joined count: 4
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
started count: 9
joined count: 5
started count: 10
joined count: 6
joined count: 7
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
joined count: 8
joined count: 9
joined count: 10
Final started count: 10, final joined count: 10
```

Could there be something else in your program you haven't posted that is causing the problem?

**Implementing a Process Pool**

If I might make a suggestion: Your method of implementing a process pool is rather inefficient. If you had 100 tasks to submit you are creating 100 processes. That is *not* the definition of a processing pool. True, you are controlling the degree of parallelism but you are failing to *reuse* processes, which is the central ideal of a pool. The following demonstrates how to create a pool of 4 processes that can execute as many tasks as required. When all the tasks are completed, you only have to join the 4 processes. This could go a long way to solving your zombie issue:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def target(queue):
    while True:
        task = queue.get()
        if task is None: # "end of file" indicator
            break
        print(f"Working for {task*2} seconds ...")
        time.sleep(task*2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_PROCESSES = 4
    processes = []
    queue = Queue()
    for _ in range(N_PROCESSES):
        processes.append(Process(target=target, args=(queue,)))
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # Write tasks to the job queue:
    for _ in range(10):
        queue.put(2)
    # And write an "end of file" indicator for each process in the pool:
    for _ in range(N_PROCESSES):
        queue.put(None)
    # Wait for processes to complete:
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Prints:

```
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ...
Working for 4 seconds ..
```

Note that you can additionally pass to each process a second queue for outputting results. Just be sure to `get` the results from this queue *before* joining the processes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestion. But, my apologies I haven't been clear enough, what I am trying to do is to spawn a new process for EACH task and never reuse the same process. How to do it without zombies ?

Comment: Well, as I said, the code you posted *appears* to be correct as I demonstrated with the limited code that you did post. But clearly your actual program is much larger and there must be some other interaction that cannot be explained by what you have shown.

Comment: You can also achieve what you want using `multiprocessing.Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)`. This will provide parallelism of 4 tasks but will create a new process for each submitted task. If you are using method `map`, be sure to specify *chunksize=1*.